# Getting an object with null value in ReactiveCrudRepository

Tags: java, spring-webflux

I used ReactiveCrudRepository but got an object with a null value for all the properties.

Author entity:

```
@Table("Author")
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Author {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long authorId;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private String nationalCode;
}
```

AuthorRepository :

```
public interface AuthorRepository extends ReactiveCrudRepository<Author, Long> {

}
```

Author Service:

```
@Service
@Transactional
public class AuthorServiceImp {

    @Autowired
    private AuthorRepository authorRepository;


    public Flux<Author> GetAllAuthor() {
        var xxxxx = authorRepository.findAll();
        xxxxx.subscribe(s->System.out.println(s));
        return xxxxx;
    }

}
```

[image]

If I used postman to call the endpoint I got what I have in console. null object

Answer (score -1, accepted):

After testing everything I understood what is the issue.
I declare the fields of the entity in camel case!!!
firstName, lastName
I just changed them to:
firstname, lastname  => in lowercase, and then everything worked fine.

Comment: Maybe you could explain why this solved your issue, by describing the request you sent, and how it is handled in the controller.

Answer (score 0):

you can try to return a `Mono<Author>` instead of `Flux<Author>` in your service method and see if the returned Author object is properly serialized.

Comment: I did but I got null for all the value even I used Mono